# MySQL: minimizing gaps between AUTO_INCREMENT row IDs

Tags: mysql, python-multithreading

Due to a race condition, and the way that MySQL increments its AUTO_INCREMENT counter, significant gaps are appearing between values of my row ID.

Background: a Python script uses multiple threads to harvest data, stored in rows of a MySQL database. Every so often several threads attempt to store the same unique row. It appears that every insert is incrementing the AUTO_INCREMENT counter, even if those inserts are causing duplicate entry exceptions, and rollback doesn't roll back the AUTO_INCREMENT counter.

Question: Is there a way to avoid the race condition, preserve sequential row IDs, and minimize the gaps? I realize that "don't worry about the gaps" is one answer. I can think of hamhanded solutions like "lock the table before checking" and "spawn another thread to keep track of sequential row IDs" but I'd like to know if there's a more clever solution.

My actual tables are fairly complex, but here's a simplified test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_thread` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `test_data` varchar(80),
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test_data_unique` (test_data)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

Here's some sample code to populate the table:

```
#!/bin/env python2.7

import os,MySQLdb,multiprocessing

MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'
MYSQL_USER = ''
MYSQL_DB   = 'packertest'
MYSQL_PASS  = ''
MYSQL_SOCKET = '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

# numerous worker threads are running simultaneously
def worker():
    # connect to the database
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYSQL_HOST, user=MYSQL_USER, db=MYSQL_DB, passwd=MYSQL_PASS, unix_socket=MYSQL_SOCKET)
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    fd = open('/usr/share/dict/words')
    # for each line in the word list...
    for line in fd.xreadlines():
        # check if this row has been added
        query = cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE `test_data`="%s"' % (line.strip()))
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            continue
        # add the row if the value isn't present
        try:
            query = cursor.execute( 'INSERT INTO test (`test_thread`,`test_data`) VALUES (%d,"%s")' % (os.getpid(),line.strip()) )
            db.commit()
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            db.rollback()

if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in range(24):
        newproc = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=())
        newproc.start()
```

And this is typical of the gaps I get:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test_id ASC;
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| test_id | test_thread | test_data |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
|       1 |       29073 | 1080      |
|       6 |       29068 | 10-point  |
|      10 |       29085 | 10th      |
|      13 |       29086 | 11-point  |
|      14 |       29078 | 12-point  |
|      23 |       29067 | 16-point  |
|      24 |       29073 | 18-point  |
```

Comment: There isn't and gaps are perfectly normal. ROLLBACK doesn't have any kind of effect on auto_increment. Every transaction is actually executed and every auto_increment column is incremented. That means that you and I might be in a transaction, you receive 1 and I receive 2 as PKs. However, your transaction failed and my didn't. Should my entire SQL start all over again so I can get that number you were assigned? And how to deal with that when there aren't 2 but thousands of users? That's why there are gaps and that's why they're fine and that's why you can't "minimize" them.

Comment: I don't think that having gaps is bad thing unless you are near field capacity limit. If you really need remove them you should write some sql procedure or script which will alter `test_id` values so there will be no gaps. But you need to remember to also change appropriate columns in related tables or use foreign keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. And you will need to run this script time to time.

Comment: @piotrekkr - one should **never** play with auto_increment and update it manually. It's a primary key, it's the *most special column that exists in the table*. If one is near exceeding the limit, then altering the table and changing to `bigint` is by far the best approach, and even if someone is near to exceed ~4.2 billion  possible entries - there are other problems that will come up. The best approach in this and any case with those "gaps" is to just let them be. Those numbers aren't supposed to be used in any kind of meaningful output when showed to people who use the app.

Comment: @N.B. I agree, that is why I wrote to try do this if he really needs to :)